# How to launch the activity of this case?

Tags: android

I have 3 activities in my app.

> Home -> List -> Detail

When I am in Detail activity, I want to have a home button that will redirect me to Home activity and close the other activities. Then, I tried this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

since the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.

I got what I want, but then it still goes to onCreate. Is there any way to launch the home and not going to its onCreate?

Comment: Whoa I'm sorry I missed this option to be declared on Activity in AndroidManifest.xml `android:launchMode="singleTask`. I will delete this question.

Comment: By using above code what you do is simply creating a new Home-Activity on top of existing Detail-Activity. Instead of that, try finishing (call finish() on) both Detail-Activity and List-Activity so that Home-Activity becomes visible.

Comment: For anyone who curious what `android:launchMode="singleTask` do, I quote this from its documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html "The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one."

Comment: Hi geeth, yes I think that what it works, but actually I miss `android:launchMode="singleTask`:)

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking and Android's are not yet fully compatible. ;)

When you "launch the home", that means it's going to be *launched*, and that means it's going to be created.

You can, however, use [`Activity.startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to start `List` and `Detail`. Your "home" button then will [`finish`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) your `Detail` Activity. In the [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) callback of `List`, you'll just pass through using `Activity.finish()`, and in `onActivityResult` of `Home` you'll just catch the event and know that you're now back.

Comment: Hi Class Stacker, actually there is a way to do it, please see my comment on my question. I only miss this option `android:launchMode="singleTask`

Comment: @Rendy Sure. I just can't imagine that this approach helps with the logic. It's usually a good idea to have a flow of control that matches the logic. Because this way, your "home" button does the opposite of the "back" button. That's no fun to implement unless your logic is extremely trivial, and even then I wouldn't do it because it's counter-intuitive. Also, there are other circumstances where your app will receive a fresh "home" `Intent`, and you want to be able to distinguish them. So, don't do it the way you think it should be done.

Comment: It's because I'm considering that actually I use lot of images in my Home activity and I don't want to reload it again and actually I don't have views that need to be refreshed. Thanks for your reminder :)

Comment: @Rendy I don't get your point. In which scenario do you think you have an advantage regarding Android not having to re-create your "home" `Activity`?

Comment: In my Home Activity, I will need to do some image processing and done by asynctask (and show progress dialog). If I re-create the Home Activity again, it will appear to user the app to be likely creating the new Home screen, not goes back to Home screen :)

Comment: @Rendy If that were true, it would be a point for going back as I suggest. However, as @m0skit0 mentioned, there's absolutely no way of controlling the Activity lifecycle, meaning that even if you go back, you can't be sure the Activity object is still sitting there -- it _might_ as well be re-created from an intent and the InstanceStae `Bundle`. But that doesn't mean you have to lose all processed data; both topics are completely unrelated. You definitely need to get a deeper understanding of Android to make reasonable design decisions.

Comment: Thanks Class Stacker for your insight, I will redesign my app :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the `Activity` life cycle. It's up to Android to decide which activities to keep running and which to close. This means that when an Activity loses focus, it is not necessarily destroyed or closed, but might simply lost focus and keep running, but might also not. This is up to Android; you cannot control this behavior.

If you want to recover an `Activity` in a given state, you have to save all needed data and restore it in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Yes we can't control the activity lifecycle. However, actually we can do it. Please see my comment above, I miss this option `android:launchMode="singleTask` :)